# In checkout page Shipping Address and Shipping method title want to make in toggle

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery

Where to add this jQuery code to make checkout page in shipping title and shipping method toggle.

```
        $('.step-title').on("click",function(){
            $(this).parent().find('#checkout-step-shipping_method').toggle();
        })

        $('#shipping .step-title').on('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().find('#checkout-step-shipping').toggle()
        })
        $('#checkout-step-shipping').css("display","none");
        $('#checkout-step-shipping_method').css("display","none");
```

Thanks.